# Why is Google Chrome so inefficient on my Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, google-chrome, memory

I have a Mac with such specification

[image]

I got used to using a few Google Chrome browsers to be opened simultaneously (each one for different task purposes). I guess that Mac OS is smart enough to keep in memory only those apps in a kind of active state that is actually in use for the current period of time. However, for the last few weeks, I noticed that my Mac started to be really slow.

I checked Activity Monitor in order to find out what consumes all the resources

I was pretty surprised when I saw that Google Chrome consumes so much:

CPU:

[image]

[image]

Memory:

[image]

[image]

When I try to click on those processes that take the biggest numbers and kill them I can see that it actually kills one of the tabs in the browser window. It is nothing special I mean it could be a tab with Google search results - which takes ~1.5Gb in memory?? Something is definitely wrong here.

Could someone point me out what can I do here?

P.S. What does it mean "(Renderer)" in the name of the process?

Comment: Why? - because Google made it that way. It's a well-known resource hog on both Mac & Win.